# Is the edh ð always curved, or can it be straight?

Tags: orthography, old-english

I'm wondering about the orthography of the old english edh ð. It is always drawn (lowercase) as a *curved* d with the line through it. But I'm wondering if it would be acceptable to just have it be a regular d with a line through it as in đ, or otherwise what other forms it could take (other than the uppercase Ð).

Comment: I am hesitant to post a real answer to this Q, as it already has 1 vote to close (lack of research, although I do not know how the average person would know how to do that in this case). Back in the day of typewriters (typewriter...what's that?)  it was acceptable to substitute đ for the Eth, as it could be written by typing a d and then over-strike with a dash. Nowadays, the đ is used more commonly in IPA or  for languages like Vietnamese (not to mention it is their currency sign) .

Comment: ...[cont.] ... Personally, I would avoid that usage as it might lead to confusion. The ð is immediately recognized as a _voiced dental fricative_ by linguists, and the use in old texts is so rampant that any substitution might be viewed with suspicion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes according to Random House Unabridged Dictionary,

***[Eth](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/edh)***:

> a letter in the form of a crossed d, ***written đ or ð***, used in Old English writing to represent both voiced and unvoiced th and in modern Icelandic and in phonetic alphabets to represent voiced th.